# Namespace declaration in separate blocks. Which is correct syntax for the function parameter?

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
//SomeStruct.h
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    typedef struct SomeStruct
    {
        int SomeVariable;
    } SomeStruct, *PSomeStruct;

}
```

and

```
//Function.h
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    Function( SomeStruct smStr );
}
```

then

```
//Function.cpp
#include "some_path_with_both_headers.h"
void SomeNameSpace::Function( SomeStruct smStr )
{ 
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
//Function.cpp
#include "some_path_with_both_headers.h"
void SomeNameSpace::Function( SomeNameSpace::SomeStruct smStr )
{ 
  ...
}
```

so that the parameter is the struct in namespace `SomeNameSpace`. The first Function.cpp is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both versions, the latter is more verbose.

The compiler already knows about the namespace of `Function` and now encounters a type it doesn't know. So it starts its search in the same namespace and finds `SomeStruct`, everything is okay. If it wouldn't find it there it would go higher up the namespace tree until it reaches the global namespace.

This is called [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (ADL) and doesn't only apply to namespaces but to classes as well.

Comment: Thanks I didn't think about the class case.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this:

```
//Function.cpp
#include "some_path_with_both_headers.h"
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    void Function( SomeStruct smStr )
    { 
        ...
    }
}
```